# Change text in HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How do I replace text in HTML with Javascript?

In the snippet below I need to replace the text "Author say" with "About the Author".

Thank you!

```
<div id="author-info">
    <div class="author-image">
        <a class="author-avatar" href="https://www.test.com"><img alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="author_name_wrap">
        <h4 class="author_name"><a href="https://www.test.com/author/">Author say</a></h4>
        <div class="author_socicons"></div>     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: on what event you want this change to happen?

Comment: how do you want to replace it? Could you be a little specific?

Comment: I want this to happen throughout the whole website

Comment: If it is on a single place in the document: `document.querySelector('h4.author_name a').innerHTML = 'About the Author'`

Comment: This question will likely be downvoted and/or closed, as you haven't provided any evidence that you've tried solving this before coming here, nor does it appear that you've done any research. SO is not a code-writing service, but rather a place to help you debug *specific* issues in your own code. Please take a minute to read **[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Comment: JavaScript can't work on an entire web site. It can only operate on the page it is loaded into.

Answer (score 0):

To change content of html tag use innerHTML property:

```
var h4 = document.getElementsByClassName("author_name")[0],
    target = h4.childNodes[0];
target.innerHTML = "About the author";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```js
document.getElementById("id-of-element").innerHTML = "new text";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="id-of-element">This text will be replaced</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple you just have to user innerText or textcontent like below example

```js
//textConent Method
    const authorName = document.querySelectorAll('author_name').textContent="Text Here"
//innerText Method
    const authorName = document.querySelectorAll('author_name').innerText="Text Here"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using [jQuery](https://jquery.com), you may change with ease.

$("h4.author_name a").text('About the Author');

You can find a detailed article [here](http://promofex.com/post/change-text-in-html-element-with-jquery)

Comment: Please note that jQuery was neither tagged nor mentioned in the question. I'd personally argue that framework answers should be avoided if OP hasn't mentioned or tagged them. Regardless, I think posting a line of jQuery code without any mention that you're using a framework/external resource is pretty useless, especially when OP isn't familiar enough with JS to do a text-replace.